# NInject v3.3.4 and WebApi 2, No parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ninject

Please help me out of a rabbit hole with NInject and Web API 2.  I have a WebApi project.  I installed the Ninject.Web.WebApi.WebHost v3.3.0 Nuget.  This brings in

- Ninject.Web.WebApi.WebHost v3.3.0
- Ninject.Web.WebApi v3.3.0
- Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost v3.3.1
- Ninject.Web.Common v3.3.1
- Ninject v3.3.4

One of these has generated a Ninject.Web.Common.cs in the App_Start folder.  I modified the RegisterServices method in it for my graph:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Load your modules or register your services here!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Load<SubscriptionApiModule>();
    }
```

The module being loaded contains a binding for IQuerySubscription:

```
    namespace SubscriptionApi.Models
    {
    ...
        public class SubscriptionApiModule : NinjectModule
        {
            public override void Load()
            {
                Bind<IQuerySubscription>().To<QueryMultipubForSubscription>();
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

I am pretty confident in the configuration for SubscriptionApiModule.  I have unit tests that provide evidence that a StandardKernel with a SubscriptionApiModule will respond to .Get requests with concrete classes I expect.

I have a few controllers.  Here is one:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/SubscriptionCheck")]
public class SubscriptionCheckController : ApiController
{
    public SubscriptionCheckController(IQuerySubscription queryService)
    {
        QueryService = queryService;
    }

    private IQuerySubscription QueryService { get; }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Heartbeat")]
    public string Heartbeat()
    {
        return "thump";
    }

    [HttpGet] 
    [Route("Get/{email}/{productCode}")]
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods:"*")]
    public async Task<bool> Get(string email, string productCode)
    {
        return await QueryService.IsSubscribed(email, productCode);
    }
}
```

I added a Heartbeat for diagnosis.  I run the API and in a browser address I enter http://localhost:xxxxx/api/SubscriptionCheck/Heartbeat and am presented with the response:

```
<Error>
    <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
    <ExceptionMessage>
        An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'SubscriptionCheckController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.
    </ExceptionMessage>
    <ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
    <StackTrace>
        at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
        </StackTrace>
        <InnerException>
            <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
            <ExceptionMessage>
                Type 'SubscriptionApi.Controllers.SubscriptionCheckController' does not have a default constructor
            </ExceptionMessage>
            <ExceptionType>System.ArgumentException</ExceptionType>
            <StackTrace>
                at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type) at System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
            </StackTrace>
        </InnerException>
</Error>
```

The container has not, apparently, been registered with the Web Api 2 framework.  I applied an old hack that used to work, sometimes.  In the CreateKernel method, after RegisterServices(kernel):

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
```

This gets me an exception at startup:

> Ninject.ActivationException
>    HResult=0x80131500
>    Message=Error activating ModelValidatorProvider using binding from ModelValidatorProvider to NinjectDefaultModelValidatorProvider
>   A cyclical dependency was detected between the constructors of two services.
>
> Activation path:
>    3) Injection of dependency ModelValidatorProvider into parameter defaultModelValidatorProviders of constructor of type DefaultModelValidatorProviders
>    2) Injection of dependency DefaultModelValidatorProviders into parameter defaultModelValidatorProviders of constructor of type NinjectDefaultModelValidatorProvider
>    1) Request for ModelValidatorProvider
>
> Suggestions:
>    1) Ensure that you have not declared a dependency for ModelValidatorProvider on any implementations of the service.
>    2) Consider combining the services into a single one to remove the cycle.
>    3) Use property injection instead of constructor injection, and implement IInitializable
>       if you need initialization logic to be run after property values have been injected.
>
> Source=
>    StackTrace:

I tried a hack I read somewhere in SO for this.  I added into the CreateKernel, under the call to RegisterServices and before the assignment to the .DependencyResolver:

```
            System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object> configuredObjects =
                GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetServices(
                    typeof(System.Web.Http.Validation.ModelValidatorProvider));
            System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Http.Validation.ModelValidatorProvider> configuredProviders =
                configuredObjects.Cast<System.Web.Http.Validation.ModelValidatorProvider>();
            Ninject.Web.WebApi.Filter.DefaultModelValidatorProviders defaultProviders =
                new Ninject.Web.WebApi.Filter.DefaultModelValidatorProviders(configuredProviders);
            kernel
                .Bind<Ninject.Web.WebApi.Filter.DefaultModelValidatorProviders>()
                .ToConstant(defaultProviders);
```

This gives me the exception:

> Ninject.ActivationException
>     HResult=0x80131500
>     Message=Error activating DefaultModelValidatorProviders
>   More than one matching bindings are available.
>   Matching bindings:
>     1) binding from DefaultModelValidatorProviders to constant value
>     2) binding from DefaultModelValidatorProviders to constant value
>   Activation path:
>     2) Injection of dependency DefaultModelValidatorProviders into parameter defaultModelValidatorProviders of constructor of type NinjectDefaultModelValidatorProvider
>     1) Request for ModelValidatorProvider
>
> Suggestions:
>     1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for DefaultModelValidatorProviders only once.
>
> Source=
>     StackTrace:

Can you offer a way I can get  NInject to be registered with WebApi controllers?

Comment: The first error tells you that: The controller cannot be created (by the DI framework) because it doesn't have a parameterless constructor. The DI is not aware of the dependency `IQuerySubscription`, so it can't create them. Make sure `IQuerySubscription` is registered in Ninject.

Comment: @jpgrass, not the answer.  I will update the statement to include a description of the module.